# How to update duplicate rows within a given condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following table:

```
 ID|group_id|subjectlist_id|article_id
 1 |1       |2             |1
 2 |2       |2             |1
 3 |3       |3             |4
 4 |4       |1             |1
 5 |5       |1             |1
```

How do I update the table so it looks like this?

```
    ID|group_id|subjectlist_id|article_id|marked
    1 |1       |2             |1         |done
    2 |2       |2             |1         |done
    3 |3       |3             |4         |
    4 |4       |1             |1         |  
    5 |5       |1             |1         |
```

So far I have this query:

```
$duplicates = DB::table('table')
    ->select('subjectlist_id', 'article_id')
    ->whereIn('group_id', array(1,2,3))
    ->groupBy('subjectlist_id', 'article_id')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
    ->update(['marked' => 'done']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')`.

If you add `DB::raw(COUNT(*))` to the select, then you can see how many records each possible combination of `subjectlist_id` and `article_id` have.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but will this list only the duplicates?

Comment: No, it will list all the rows including the rows that are identical and tell you which ones have duplicates and how many duplicates there are via the count column

Comment: I've edited the question so it sounds clearer than trying to explain it